# Conditional CSS query for WebViews

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I serve different contents for desktop and mobile browser visitors. Mostly I handle them by using [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)'s "visible-xs", "visible-desktop" classes. Due to some concerns I need to specialize some of the contents.

For example
if user is desktop browser or mobile browser: content will be visible
if user comes from my mobile application's webview: content will not be visible
(I change my Application WebView's user agent to my specified string)

As far as I know there exists other media query options [like this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1). But media queries doesn't have an option to trigger the content with respect to user agent.

Of course it is possible to trigger to show or hide content with javascript by using `navigator.userAgent`. But I search for a CSS way.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment when you change "WebView's user agent to my specified string" you can add, let's say, "mode" attribute to root element of your document (usually it is `<html>`) with values like "compact" and "roomy".

These two CSS rules:

```
:root[mode=compact] [roomy] { display:none; }
:root[mode=roomy] [compact] { display:none; }
```

will allow you to define visibility of particular elements for particular view models. Like that:

```
<p compact>This is seen in compact mode</p>
<p roomy>This is seen in roomy mode</p>
```